# Is it possible to set web part criteria based on value from a list?

Tags: 2013, web-part

I have a sharepoint list with current and upcoming cases, and a list of years in which these cases will be completed.
I would like to create a page with web parts showing cases for each year currently in the years list (there will always be four).

I can manually adjust the criteria to match the year, in the view settings, but I would like this to update automatically when the list of years is updated. Is this possible, and how would I go about doing this?

E.g. 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021 in the years list may give:

```
    2018    2019    2020    2021

    Case1   Case2   Case3   Case4

    Case7   Case6   Case9   Case8
```

Comment: do you mean , you have another list which has year as item and only cases corresponding to those years are shown? or is it dropdown on the page?

Comment: I have another list with year as the items

Comment: it is not so easy to dynamically filter by 4 years in another list, just for simple, edit the view filter in WebParts. This is the most simply and efective solution, you must to do it once per year...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, Cases list has Year column as well.

You can use connected web-parts

1. First webpart will be filter with year column from Year lisr
2. Connect this to the second webpart which will be list of cases
3. Users can choose Year from first webpart and cases will be filtered automatically accordingly.

Below links might help you

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/connect-a-filter-web-part-to-a-list-view-web-part-on-a-classic-page-4f3f6c10-0a1b-479d-8b4d-c4f1bf49bb3f

https://blog.splibrarian.com/2012/05/21/connecting-web-parts-with-a-selector-and-a-detail-pane-sharepoint-2010-version/

Comment: Thanks @Rohit. There is a Year column in Cases as well, so your solution would work. I am after a solution that would automate this based on the years currently in the Years list.

Comment: First webpart will fetch all years from years list automatically and then can be used to filter cases....am I missing something?

Comment: I would like the result to be a page that already has a list for each of the four years, rather than the ability to filter by year.